# SQL help needed - keeping track of sent emails

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables. A user table. A poem table. A table that keeps track of what poems have been emailed to what users.

```
tblUser  | tblEmailed  | tblPoems
-------  | ----------- | --------
userid   | userid      | poemid
username | poemid      | poemname
etc      | date        | etc
```

I want to write one MySQL query that selects a userid that hasn't been emailed a poem today AND selects a poemid that they haven't received before.

Can someone help me?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with this after realizing I cannot to this with one query:

```
SELECT * FROM tblUser U 
LEFT JOIN tblEmailed E ON E.userid = U.userid AND E.date = CURDATE()
WHERE E.userid IS NULL 
LIMIT 1

SELECT * FROM tblPoems P 
LEFT JOIN tblEmailed E ON E.poemid = P.poemid AND E.userid = :userid
WHERE E.poemid IS NULL 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: You can do this with one query

Comment: Strawberry, please enlighten me.

Comment: See my comment to your original post

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you will need to do is determine a user that hasn't been emailed today. To do that you can use something like the following:

`SELECT u.userid
 FROM tblUser u
 LEFT JOIN tblemailed e on e.userid = u.userid
 WHERE e.date == CURDATE() AND COALESCE(e.poemid, '') == ''
 LIMIT 1`

Then we will need that `user_id` in order to find a poem they have yet to receive:

`SELECT p.poemid
 FROM tblPoems p
 WHERE p.poemid NOT IN (SELECT poemid FROM tblEmailed WHERE userid == user_id)
 LIMIT 1`

where `user_id` is the user from the first query.

Comment: Or just use the right kind of join

Comment: Note that `LEFT JOIN x ... WHERE x =...` is the same as `INNER JOIN x`, and LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: He/she asked for one result and seems to be new with SQL, hence the `LIMIT`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I disagree that an INNER JOIN is appropriate here at all.

Comment: To be blunt, that's because you don't understand what you're doing. To understand how your query is interpreted by the optimiser, run EXPLAIN EXTENDED followed by SHOW WARNINGS. Perhaps then you'll appreciate the fallacy of your own logic.

Comment: There's no insult here.